# Java - boolean set to false with nothing telling it to do so

Tags: java, boolean

My boolean drawFlag is being set to false in my code with nothing visible actually telling it to change value to false. This is preventing the code inside method mouseDragged(mouseEvent) to execute. If someone could point out what's making the flag become false so this would stop happening? Thanks.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DrawAndDrag {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        GraphicsFrame window = new GraphicsFrame("Draw Rectangle");
        window.init();
    }
}

class GraphicsFrame extends JFrame {

    public GraphicsFrame(String title) {
        super(title);
    }

    public void init() {
        Container pane = this.getContentPane();
        pane.add(new GraphicsContent().init());
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(600, 600);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class GraphicsContent extends JPanel {
    private int xStart, yStart;
    private int width, height;

    public JPanel init() {
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseDrag());
        this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseDrag());
        return this;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(xStart, yStart, width, height);
    }

    class MouseDrag implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
        private boolean drawFlag;

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if(isOutside(e)) {
                this.drawFlag = true;
                xStart = e.getX();
                yStart = e.getY();
                width = 0; height = 0;
                System.out.println(drawFlag);
            }else {
//              this.drawFlag = false;
            }
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(drawFlag);
            if(drawFlag) {
                width = e.getX() - xStart;
                height = e.getY() - yStart;
                repaint();
            }
        }

        public boolean isOutside(MouseEvent e) {
            int xMin = Math.min(xStart, xStart + width);    int yMin = Math.min(yStart, yStart + height);
            int xMax = Math.max(xStart, xStart + width);    int yMax = Math.max(yStart, yStart + height);

            if((e.getX() < xMin || e.getX() > xMax)
            || (e.getY() < yMin || e.getY() > yMax)) {
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: The default value of `drawFlag` is false. Is the code setting it to true ever executed?

Comment: Yes, when you click outside of the drawn rectangle, the boolean gets set to true. However as you drag, the value is constantly being reported as being false, even though there is no code resetting the boolean value.

Comment: stop posting duplicates of questions that are getting closed, they are getting closed for valid reasons

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you sure you need two MouseDrag elements? I.e. using something like

```
public JPanel init() {
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    MouseDrag md = new MouseDrag();
    this.addMouseListener(md);
    this.addMouseMotionListener(md);
    return this;
}
```

I can at least plot a blue square....

Comment: Yes that's the route of the problem, both methods were referring to a different value, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to move `drawFlag` attribute from the inner class `MouseDrag` to the outer class `GraphicsContent` as follow

```
class GraphicsContent extends JPanel {
    private int xStart, yStart;
    private int width, height;
    private volatile boolean drawFlag;

    // other code

}
```

Comment: @Squiffy Have you tried my solution? I tested it here in my IDE and it works.

Comment: Ahh now its doing just what I wanted it to do, thanks! Was my problem that there were two different instances of MouseDrag, one invoking mousePressed() and the other invoking mouseDragged() such that they were sharing the same value?

Comment: @Radiodef What do you think about this problem's cause? I think it is related to scopes or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

> However **as you drag**, the value is constantly being reported as being false

You've got two listeners. One is a motion listener:

```
this.addMouseListener(new MouseDrag());
this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseDrag());
```

`mousePressed` will not be called on a motion listener, so it will always be false in the drag event.

I expect what you meant is this:

```
MouseDrag listener = new MouseDrag();
this.addMouseListener(listener);
this.addMouseMotionListener(listener);
```